# Google Tag Manager: Setting up rules for different domains

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

What is the best method to fire GA tags depending on the domain? I want to create one container which will hold several GA accounts for multiple ccTLDs. Is it best to use a {{url}} rule that contains example.co.uk and then another for {{url}} contains example.com. If doing this way is it better to use 'contains' or RegEx? ...

Or should I create data layer with the domain name and then fire the GA tags whenever that data layer is on the page? Which is the best practice?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm...creating a dataLayer variable for the tld wouldn't make much sense as you can already get that info from the URL.

Personally, I always go with matches RegEx because contains has always been vague in terms of what is going to be included.

I would say the best way to fire tags based in the tld is to use {{URL}} matches RegEx example.com

Comment: Hey @Blexy thanks for that tip. Yes, I was kinda thinking the same, so thanks for confirming.